# Programmatically Created ImageButton Inside HorizontalScrollView Not Receiving Touch

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to get my ImageButtons responding to a touch event. These ImageButtons are created dynamically and added to LinearLayouts inside a HorizontalScrollView which are set up in a layout resource.

**HOW I ADD THE IMAGEBUTTON**

```
            ImageButton button = new ImageButton( getActivity() );
            button.setBackgroundResource( plugin.mIcon.mBackgroundID );
            button.setImageResource( plugin.mIcon.mIconID );
            button.setEnabled( plugin.isEnabled() );
            // need to set the layout parameters of this button.
            currentLayout.addView(button);
            // we have to setup the layout parameters after it has been added to its parent.
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = UnitConversionUtils.dipToPixels(getActivity(), PLUGIN_BUTTON_SIDE).intValue();
            params.height = UnitConversionUtils.dipToPixels( getActivity(), PLUGIN_BUTTON_SIDE).intValue();
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
            button.setOnClickListener( this );
```

**MY IMAGEBUTTON ONCLICKLISTENER**

I have set my listener up in two different ways just to try and get it working.

```
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.d("Fragment","ImageButton clicked");
    }
});
```

and also when I set the button's listener to this, it is a Fragment that's implement `View.OnClickListener` and has the `public void onClick(View v);` method implemented.

**XML LAYOUT RESOURCE**

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/map_plugin_scroll_view"
        android:background="@color/mm_map_drawer_background">

        <!-- Enclosing box to layout the two groups.-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/group_container">

            <!-- These layouts contain the map plugins. -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/group_one"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/group_two"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I'm assuming the HorizontalScrollView is consuming the touch but I'm not sure. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: based on your code, it doesn't look like the button would do anything when pressed (the onClickListener is "this" but you don't show that code) and parent views should propagate touch events to child views.

Comment: Sorry @Jim I didn't include that code. All I do is implement View.OnClickListener in my fragment and log when called. Do you think it's the HorizontalScrollView thats consuming the touch?

Comment: No - it's probably in the listener. Try creating a separate object for the listener or post more code / logs to explain the problem better

Comment: are your buttons enabled? and do you see any log activity?

Comment: Jim, you're a genius. I stupidly forgot I changed the variable I was using to enable the button! Please put this check as the answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is on this line:

```
button.setEnabled( plugin.isEnabled() );
```

Sometimes it's the little things!

Comment: I thought to myself, I've used onClickListeners hundreds of times, surely I couldn't be that stupid... Thanks!